# Import displays DICOM images as black rectangles (Mma v. 10)

Tags: image, version-10

My problem concerns Mathematica version 10.0.1.0 with OS X 10.9.4, OS X 10.9.5 and it does not occur in Mathematica version 9.0.1.0 (on the same computer and OS).

About 90% of my DICOM images are displayed as black rectangles when I use the Import function directly (giving only the name of the file). However, if I specify to Import only the « Graphics » element from the file, the image is displayed correctly !

Actually, it is easy to test, I could reproduce the problem with the image example in the Mathematica Documentation (see ref/format/DICOM) :

```
Import["ExampleData/head.dcm.gz"]
```

gives me a black rectangle only

and with

```
Import["ExampleData/head.dcm.gz", "Graphics"]
```

the image is displayed correctly.

Does Anyone have the same behaviour (bug?) with version 10 ?

(Once again, i don’t have this problem with version 9.)

---

***UPDATE***

***The problem comes from a wrong (or lack of) data normalisation, resulting in some very darkened images (so dark that I thought they were entirely black !).

The responsible for that behaviour seems clearly to be the `Image` function which does not handle correctly `Graphics[Raster[...]]` anymore.***

Here are some detailed observations :

***1/*** the "black" rectangle displayed by Import is not all black !  Actually it is the image, but it is highly darkened.  :

[image]

[image]

***2/*** I have also noticed that the imported image Type is `Bit16` and that the `ColorSpace` is `Grayscale` whereas in Mathematica 9 it is respectively `Byte` and `RGB` ...This is curious, the original data seems indeed to be `Bit16` ...

[image]

***3/*** The pixels values in the "black" image correspond to the original data values divided by (2^16 -1).

[image]

***4/*** These pixel values should have been automatically normalized so the maximum value in the original data (=1727) would correspond to the max intensity (= 1) in the image.

Actually, this normalisation is correctly done when I Import the image as a Graphic object :

[image]

The function `Import` seems to check automatically in the data what is the max intensity value (=1727) and the correct dimensions (512x512) to use for the display : these informations are explicitly included in the imported graphic.

[image]

***5/*** Now, if I try to convert the correctly imported graphic to an image using the `Image` function, the result is the same "black" rectangle I had with the default Import in 1/.

[image]

***6/*** The `Image` function seems to be the origin of the problem. On my computer, it clearly does not take into account anymore the multiple parameter form of `Raster`.

Here are some basic examples where I try to convert a simple `Graphic[Raster[...]]` to an `Image Object` : the pictures should be identical but it does not work here with my version 10.0.1 (it does work with my version 9)

[image]

[image]

---

I am very surprised, it seems the problem is only specific to my computer ?!?!  (... no one yet has reported a similar problem.

Are there some general tests/checking I could do to understand why this problem is specific to my computer only ? ( For example I have already checked there is no problem with the dynamic libraries the Mathematica executables are linked to - it seems fine except maybe for libz.1.dylib).

Also I thought that maybe Mathematica 10 is interfering with Mathematica 9 (both versions are installed on my computer and I have no problem with M9). Would that be possible ?

Any hint/idea is welcome.

Comment: The example image imports correctly for me on v10 OS X

Comment: This is not specific to your computer; the behavior changed between V10.0.0 and V10.0.1.  The switch to grayscale makes sense to me, but I don't know why it doesn't rescale appropriately.  `ImageAdjust` is a useful function.