# Raster to Image conversion problem

Tags: graphics, bugs, image, rasterize

**Bug introduced in v9 or earlier and persisting through v10.3.0**

---

There are 3 ways to convert a `Raster` into an `Image` : only 1 works for me with versions 10.0.1,10.0.2,10.1.0,10.2.0,10.3.0 , and  2 work with version 9 (same computer, OS X 10.9.5)

Has anyone the same problem or is it localized to me and why ?

(This question is actually related to a previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60462/import-displays-dicom-images-as-black-rectangles-mma-v-10) concerning a problem to import DICOM images)

Here are the tests :

**0. The test object**

First, let' s define the test object : a `Raster` with specific rectangular shape and scale.

```
data = {{-90, 1, 50}, {30, 0.5, -30}, {75, 1000, -1900}};
shape = {{0, 0}, {10, 2}};
scale = {-100, 100};

myraster = Raster[data, shape, scale];
```

This is how it looks :

```
Graphics[myraster, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

For comparison, this is how it looks when you omit the shape and scale :

```
Graphics[Raster[data], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

**1. `Image@Raster`**

According to the documentation (V9 or v10), it should be possible to convert a `Raster` primitive directly into an Image object :

[image: doc. Raster]

Whether I am using version 9 or 10.0.1, **the raster is not correctly converted**: the shape and scale of the raster were not taken into account !?

```
Image@myraster
Through@{Head, ImageType, ImageDimensions, Options}[%]
```

[image]

In versions 10.0.2, 10.1.0, 10.2.0,10.3.0 the output is a little bit different but still **not correct**:

[image]

**2. `Image@Graphics@Raster`**

This conversion **works in version 9** but **not in version 10.0.1, 10.0.2, 10.1.0, 10.2.0**

```
Image@Graphics@myraster
Through@{Head, ImageType, ImageDimensions, Options}[%]
```

The result looks like `Image@Raster`:

v10.0.1:

[image]

v10.0.2, v10.1.0, v10.2.0, v10.3.0:

[image]

v.9 : **OK** !

[image]

**3. `Rasterize`**: OK but ...

According to the documentation (V9 or v10), `Image@Graphics` effectively uses the `Rasterize` function.

[image]

This is OK, it works for me the same way with both v9, but also with v10.0.1, v10.0.2, v10.1.0, v10.2.0, v10.3.0 !

[image]

***But how is it possible that in v10,  Image@Graphics does not work if it effectively uses Rasterize which does work ... !??***

**4. To sum up**

[image]

Comment: **All:** Based on my analysis (below) I believe this is a bug therefore I am tagging it as such.  If anyone disagrees please let me know!

Comment: Has there been any attempt to fix the bug?

Comment: @AliHashmi Probably no as it is still the same problem in v. 11.3.0 (at least on OSX).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question.  I believe it is the result of an incomplete attempt to optimize conversion of `Raster` objects to `Image` objects; a bug in other words.  Note that when the axes are included the output is correct:

```
Image @ Graphics[myraster, Axes -> True]  (* v10.0.1 *)
```

[image]

### `Trace` of the correct conversion

Running a [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) with option `TraceInternal -> True` on `Image @ Graphics[myraster, Axes -> True]` (very slow to print) reveals that this call is made:

```
MathLink`FrontEndBlock[
 MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
  ExportPacket[
   Notebook[{Cell[
      BoxData[GraphicsBox[
        RasterBox[{{-90, 1, 50}, {30, 0.5`, -30}, {75, 1000, -1900}}, {{0, 0}, {10, 
           2}}, {-100, 100}], Axes -> True]], "Output", ShowCellBracket -> False, 
      Magnification -> 1.`, Background -> Automatic, CellContext -> "Global`", 
      GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> Medium}, 
      Graphics3DBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> Medium}, 
      InsetBoxOptions -> {DefaultBaseStyle -> {"Inset", 
          GraphicsBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> Automatic}, 
          Graphics3DBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> Automatic}}}]}, 
    WindowSize -> {550.`, 360.`}], "BitmapPacket", 
   ColorSpace -> RGBColor, Verbose -> True, "AlphaChannel" -> False, 
   "DataCompression" -> True]], LinkObject["daahs_shm", 3, 1]]
```

This sends an `ExportPacket` of type `"BitmapPacket"` to `LinkObject["daahs_shm", 3, 1]` which is apparently a library that does the actual conversion.

**Note that the complete `Raster` data is preserved in this `ExportPacket` in the form of a `RasterBox`.**

- The same call appears in the `Trace` of `Rasterize @ Graphics @ myraster` in v10 and in *Mathematica* 7.0.1 when evaluating `Image @ Graphics @ myraster` except for a few variations such as the name of the `LinkObject`.

### `Trace` of the incorrect conversion

However when `Image[myraster]` is used something else entirely is observed.  First it is handed off to:

```
Image`FromRaster[Raster[{{-90,1,50},{30,0.5,-30},{75,1000,-1900}},{{0,0},{10,2}},{-100,100}]]
```

The array data is extracted (omitting your `shape` and `scale` data):

```
Image`ImageDump`array$2281 = 
 Raster[{{-90, 1, 50}, {30, 0.5, -30}, {75, 1000, -1900}}, {{0, 0}, {10, 2}}, {-100, 
    100}][[1]]
```

> ```
> {{-90, 1, 50}, {30, 0.5, -30}, {75, 1000, -1900}}
> ```

This data is "massaged" a bit for color space, packing, etc., then sent to `Image`, e.g.:

```
Image[Image`ImageDump`array$2281, OptionValue[Image`ImageDump`info$2279, DataType], 
 ColorSpace -> Image`ImageDump`cs$2281, Interleaving -> Image`ImageDump`il$2281]
```

Some other options are used but **nowhere in this call is the `shape` or `scale` data used.**

When the `Graphics` expression contains only a `Raster` a different function is called but the result is the same.  First it is passed to:

```
Image`FromGraphicsRaster[\!\(\*
GraphicsBox[
    RasterBox[{{-90, 1, 50}, {30, 0.5, -30}, {75, 1000, -1900}}, {{0, 0}, {10, 2}}, {-100,
      100}]]\)]
```

So we have conversion to Box form, unlike `Image[myraster]`, but then the array data is extracted and passed to `Image` as above, again without accounting for the second and third parameters of `Raster` (or `RasterBox`) as far as I can tell.

It is worth noting that the Trace on `Image[myraster]` is much shorter than on the full conversion shown at the top of this answer, so the idea of optimization is *not* misplaced.  However it is not yet complete.

### Proposed workaround

For now it is possible to bypass this incomplete optimization merely by wrapping the `Raster` in `List`:

```
Image @ Graphics[{myraster}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! And, what is your conclusion concerning Rasterize ?

Comment: Also, please could you tell me what is the exact syntax you use to Trace. Before posting I tried that on Image, but for example the output of `Trace[Image[myraster]]` gives me no information (it just repeats the command, shows the data and the result, that's all ...). But using the same form to Trace Rasterize, it gives me pages of detailed info ...

Comment: @SquareOne I did not Trace `Rasterize` yet but I will do so.  I expect that a similar `ExportPacket` call will occur.  For `Trace` you need to add the option `TraceInternal -> True` to see behind the curtain but be careful as there is a considerable chance you will hang *Mathematica*.  In v10 the front end freezes while printing (unlike v7) but it is still working so be patient; however you should watch the RAM usage as it continually increases and you may need to terminate *Mathematica*.

Comment: @SquareOne If printing the entire trace (i.e. "show all") is not possible you will have to capture the output of `Trace` and view it one piece at a time.

Comment: @SquareOne I confirmed that `Rasterize` is performing the same conversion and included this note in my answer.

Comment: +1 A nice bit of detective work. I think you are correct about the optimisation. If you set `SetSystemOptions["ImageProcessingOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> True}]` you get some debug output referring to "fast conversion".

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Pleasure to read :) +1